# if-else not working in __construct()

Tags: php, session, constructor

php's `if else` is not working in `__construct()`. If SESSION is not empty, i create it, and log, else I log it. But none of logs happens { if {} { log } else { log}. It logs only the last line after if else.

```
<?php

class Controller  {

    public function __construct() {

        // parent::__construct(); 


        if( empty($_SESSION) ) {
            $nowStr = '' . time() .'_';
            $sesname = !empty( $givArr['sesname'] ) ? $givArr['sesname'] : uniqid ($nowStr).uniqid() ;
            $oldSesname = session_name($sesname);
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['name']=$sesname;
            file_put_contents( PATH_LOG . 'n ses171113', PHP_EOL.' ###################### src\core\Controller.php   STARTED _SESSION='. json_encode( $_SESSION ) . PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND ) ;
        } // DOES NOT LOG NEVER 
        else {
            file_put_contents( PATH_LOG . ' ses171113', PHP_EOL.' ###################### src\core\Controller.php   CONTINUE _SESSION='. json_encode( $_SESSION ) . PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND ) ;
        } // DOES NOT LOG NEVER 

        file_put_contents( PATH_LOG . ' ses171113', PHP_EOL.' ###################### src\core\Controller.php   case out of scope =' . PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND ) ;  //  LOGS

    }
```

Comment: Dunno, but `$givArr` is always empty.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Try `if (!isset($_SESSION))` instead of `if (empty($_SESSION))`

Comment: `Try if (!isset($_SESSION)) instead of if (empty($_SESSION)) ` - @HtmHell - that's silly advice. Superglobals are always set

Comment: It's possible that `PATH_LOG . 'n ses171113'` can't be written to, while `PATH_LOG . ' ses171113'` can be written to.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Then why when I'm dumping `$_SESSION` without `session_start()` I'm getting `Undefined variable: _SESSION` error? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e705cf7442a131924c5532addea45f9e334e13a

Comment: thank you, the error was in log path, it was logging to a different file

Answer (score 1):

Your code is broken. `$_SESSION` is superglobal, so checking if it exists if futile is you started the session. Aside from that you access `$givArr` which is non existing variable.

I strongly recommend you do `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very first line of your scripts as you are simply muting all the useful error reports. Also static analysis of your code is something you should consider doing.

Comment: I am sorry, $givArr is defined above, and i use` error_reporting(E_ALL);`, just i do not put all code here, because this is a piece of controller method/action, while error_reporting is defined in index.php. Sometimes i am tired, and make typo mistakes, which produce wierd behaviour, like in the case above, the wrong file name.